# Unable to play WAV file generated by IBM Watson's TTS (Text To Speech)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, subprocess, ibm-cloud

Currently working with the example script found on IBM Watson's GitHub:

- Link: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/text_to_speech_v1.py

When I run the script, it works perfectly creating the WAV file. However, when I try to play it back within the script, it simply runs and never plays. I tried using PyAudio, Os, Subprocess, and other third party libraries to play the file, however, nothing worked. Is there something I would have to do to the file first before attempting to play it in the script? I'm assuming it has something to do with it being written in binary, which is what the script calls for, but I'm still too new at programming to understand how to solve the problem.

I'll attach my full script below with placeholders for personal info. Thanks!

```
# coding=utf-8
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import TextToSpeechV1
from watson_developer_cloud.websocket import SynthesizeCallback
import subprocess

service = TextToSpeechV1(url='EXAMPLE URL TO API', iam_apikey='EXAMPLE API KEY')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), '..EXAMPLE PATH../resources/output2.wav'),'wb') as audio_file:
    response = service.synthesize("What's the weather?", accept='audio/wav', voice="en-US_MichaelVoice").get_result()
    audio_file.write(response.content)

def audio_call():
    audio_file_path = "..EXAMPLE PATH../resources/output2.wav"
    return subprocess.call(["afplay", audio_file_path])
audio_call()
```

Comment: Are you sure the `.wav` file being produced is playable? Try doing it manually with some other application to verify this.

Comment: It is, I opened it through iTunes and other apps. Plays there just fine.

Comment: Does the `audio_file_path `contain space characters? You may have to enclose it in double quote characters. Also, are you getting any kind of error messages?

Comment: What does running `file "..EXAMPLE PATH../resources/output2.wav"` says about the file?

Comment: @martineau I gave that a shot, still nothing unfortunately.

Comment: I meant to literally put them into the string element in the list being passed to `subprocess.call()` — which could be done with  `audio_file_path = '"..EXAMPLE PATH../resources/output2.wav"'`.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]: Apparently there was a problem with my file directory playing WAV files. By changing the file acceptance to "accept = 'audio/wav'" it worked fine.